# Field Service Lightning in Winter '17

Tags: winter17, fieldservice, field-service-lightning

I see that in Winter '17, a number of standard field service objects are added that replicate the functionality of the custom objects in Field Service Lightning's managed package. At this time I have not found any information on the next release of the managed package.

My company is setting up an org for a client that will use Field Service Lightning. Once Winter '17 rolls out, we'll have the odd situation of using the FSL managed package written for the previous API release, and hence using all these custom versions of what are now standard objects.

Can anyone shed some light on how the next release of the FSL managed package will reconcile this? Will it shift to using the standard objects instead? If our client is going to be using FSL and we're working on the system **now**, should we just ignore the new objects for this client?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be late for you, but I'll add an answer to this question as I stumbled upon it while doing the research on the FLS Managed package.

Salesforce has released a guide for migrating to the new standard object model of FSL. You can find this guide [here](https://fsl.secure.force.com/install/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01536000002OYCz). In case that link expires for some reason here's a link to the latest [FLS Managed Package](https://fsl.secure.force.com/install/) that also contains additional documentation and a link to the migration guide.

You will, of course, get a better picture if you go through the guide yourself but, in a nutshell, this is what the guide says:

> While there is no rush to upgrade an existing live implementation, plans should be prepared for migration
>   specifically to ensure a smooth transition once required. Salesforce will continue to support existing
>   customers and produce patches with bug fixes for urgent product issues that arise.
>
> If you are not sure when the right time to migrate is, please open a case with our support team and we will
>   gladly advise on next actions recommended. The migration
>   effort will vary from one implementation to the next and it is important to ask your implementer for an effort
>   estimate before beginning to migrate

Comment: Thank you. At the time of writing we had no choice but to proceed full-on with customizing the old managed package objects and loading years of data into them. The client is still on the old package and there is no migration plan because nobody can yet justify the cost of paying us to migrate those customizations.